# Json Object, rearrange CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css, json

I am having trouble rearrange my divs that are set to .sortable in Jquery.  Basically I can move my divs and I save the ID and top and left once moved.  I am then calling data back from a json file.  My problem is when I call this data back I am having trouble moving my divs as per the way they were saved.  Below is what I have so far:

```
$.getJSON("http://test.com/test", function( json) {
  $.each( json, function( key, val ) {    

  $("#" + val.divname).animate({left: val.left+ "px"}, 1000);


 });   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Impossible to follow, but try with https://api.jquery.com/offset and https://api.jquery.com/position/‎.

For that, you will need to `$("#" + val.divname).animate({left: $(val).offset().left + "px"}, 1000);`

Comment: Still no joy, my Json text is below [{"divname" : "GB_2", "top" : "124", "left" : "192"},{"divname" : "3_Gb", "top" : "124", "left" : "452"},

Comment: I want to move my div, based on the id (GB_2) too the top value(124) and left value(192).  Hope that makes sense.  Many Thnaks

Comment: Oh, I see. You saved the properties of your div. How "position" for your divs are set?. I think it should be "position:fixed;".

Comment: $("#" + val.divname).animate({height: val.top + "px"}, 1000); The above amends the height, but i can not seem to amend the position of each div?  Help please!

Comment: <div id="Box-wrapper">
Below is the struture of my divs, the movable div is called ui-state-default.  Ive just notice it has no CSS behind it tho?     <div id="contents">
     <ul id="sortable">
          <li class="ui-state-default" ID="GB_1">

Comment: I believe this is the correct syntax, but my javascript stops working, i dont believe i am entering my two variables correctly?  Many Thansk                                                          $("#" + val.divname).css({left:" + val.left + "px"});